# opessl sha-512 string charset

Tags: linux, encryption, cryptography

The utility `openssl` can be used to generate a sha512 based hash from a given string.
What is the possible range of characters it can produce in output. I mean that what all characters can the result produce. I am not able to find any documentation for the same.

```
openssl passwd -6
Password: 
Verifying - Password: 
$6$qJV2Hr9qSOw4/Zxx$pVe4wDNy1mDRIAcPrIWEr0dCzpZQDS2Zb83Ix2pktuCd5jEwvQjO8EiDMFtlAQ/TfYXucKO8qWf9NtLQPbdgi1
```

The above is an example of sha-512 hashed string using `'openssl'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the possible range of characters SHA-512 can produce?

All 256 possible byte values, like with every other relevant hashing function. However, because the output is effectively random, binary data, hash values are almost always encoded to represent them as plain (ASCII) text. base16 (hex) and base64 are popular. Each encoding has its own alphabet.

> ```
> $6$qJV2Hr9qSOw4/Zxx$pVe4wDNy1mDRIAcPrIWEr0dCzpZQDS2Zb83Ix2pktuCd5jEwvQjO8EiDMFtlAQ/TfYXucKO8qWf9NtLQPbdgi1
> ```
>
> The above is an example of SHA-512 hashed string using 'openssl'

No, not really. It's a password hash in [crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)) format. The selected mode is based on SHA-512, but the output encodes much more information than just a SHA-512 hash value. To the best of my knowledge there is no formal specification of the crypt format.

Assuming that no parameter pairs are included (which openssl doesn't output as far as I know), the alphabet is that of base64 plus `'$'` and `'.'` which serve as separators.

To fully support all possible values in Modular Crypt Format, including those with key-value parameters (as in `$md5,rounds=5000$GUBv0xjJ$$mSwgIswdjlTY0YxV7HBVm0`) you should probably expect all printable ASCII characters, but at least `'='` in addition to those mentioned above.

Comment: [Here](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=33) is an informal description of the process. I have no idea if it is accurate.

Comment: AFAIK `.` is not a separator in [B64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#B64), but a character of the alphabet (instead `+` is missing compared to Base64). However, `.` does not replace `+` because the alphabets of Base64 and B64 have (almost) identical characters though, but a different order.